# Bash Scripting - If statement not behaving as intended

Tags: bash, if-statement, echo, user-input, logical-or

This is my first time playing with bash scripting, but I just cannot understand why this if statement is not behaving. No matter what input I enter into the choice variable as input I always get returned the first echo which should only execute if I input anything other than yes or no.

I've tried removing brackets, enclosing in double quotes, but I just can't make sense of this.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Would you like to take driving lessons: ' choice
read -p 'Type your age: ' age

if [ $choice != 'yes' ] || [ $choice != 'no' ] 
then 
  echo 'Your choice must be either yes or no'
fi
```

Here is the output:

```
$ ./test.sh        
Would you like to take driving lessons: yes
Type your age: 46
Your choice must be either yes or no
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$ ./test.sh        
Would you like to take driving lessons: no
Type your age: 63
Your choice must be either yes or no
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$ ./test.sh
Would you like to take driving lessons: dgdgf
Type your age: 76
Your choice must be either yes or no
```

Only the last run should return the echo statement.

Comment: Combining negative tests can be unintuitive. [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) explain why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. You need `&&` when it's not equal to.
This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Would you like to take driving lessons: ' choice
read -p 'Type your age: ' age

if [ $choice != 'yes' ] && [ $choice != 'no' ];
then
  echo 'Your choice must be either yes or no'
fi
```

It gives the following output:

```
~ bash test.sh
Would you like to take driving lessons: yes
Type your age: 432
~ bash test.sh
Would you like to take driving lessons: fdsa
Type your age: 32
Your choice must be either yes or no
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Would you like to take driving lessons: ' choice
read -p 'Type your age: ' age

if [ $choice != 'yes' ] && [ $choice != 'no' ]
then
  echo 'Your choice must be either yes or no'
fi
```